# How to pass an array to constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I'm trying to learn Java, but I have a problem with passing an array to constructor.
For example:

Application class:
`byte[][] array = new byte[5][5];
targetClass target = new targetClass(array[5][5]);`

Target class:

```
public class targetClass {
    /* Attributes */
    private byte[][] array = new byte[5][5];

    /* Constructor */
    public targetClass (byte[][] array) {
        this.array[5][5] = array[5][5];
    }

}
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if you could show me how I can do that.

Comment: Since you are learning Java, the class name should always start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, usually class names in Java starts with Upper case, now, to the problem you met, it should be:

```
public class TargetClass { /* Attributes */ 
    private byte[][] array;

    /* Constructor */
    public TargetClass (byte[][] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BlagovestBalchev well that's the best part! :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to intialize array in the class at the time of declaration. It can be set to the passed array's reference. For example,

```
public class targetClass { 
    /* Attributes */ 
    private byte[][] array = null; 

    /* Constructor */ 
    public targetClass (byte[][] array) { 
        this.array = array; 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your application class, the following should work:

```
byte[][] array = new byte[5][5];
TargetClass target = new TargetClass(array); // Not array[5][5]
```

In addition, for your target class, the following should work:

```
public class TargetClass {
    /* Attributes */
    private byte[][] array; // No need to explicitly define array

    /* Constructor */
    public TargetClass (byte[][] array) {
        this.array = array; // Not array[5][5]
    }
}
```

As mentioned, class names are usually capitalized, so that's what I've done to your class names.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class targetClass {
    /* Attributes */
    private byte[][] array = null;

    /* Constructor */
    public targetClass (byte[][] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

}
```

Then call it like this

```
byte[][] array = new byte[5][5]; 
targetClass target = new targetClass(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you're trying to assign the private array to the passed in array, rather than trying to pick the 5,5 element out of the passed-in array.

Inside the constructor, the syntax should be:

> this.array = array;

In the application, it should be

> targetClass target = new targetClass(array);

Answer (score 0):

To pass an array to a constructor we need to pass in the array variable to the constructor while creating an object.

So how we can store that array in our class for further operations.

- We need an instance variable to store that
  in our case it can be `private byte[][] array;`
- We don't need to assign memory to it as that would get wasted because later it will be pointing to the original arrays heap location in the memory.
- We can copy the array using various techniques

  ```
    public class targetClass {
    /* Attributes */
    private byte[][] array = new byte[5][5];

    /* Constructor */
    public targetClass (byte[][] array) {
        this.array  = array;
        this.array = array.clone();//If you want separate object instance on heap
    }
  }
  byte[][] data = new byte[10][10];
  targetClass t1 = new targetClass(data);
  ```